# C# WINDOWS FORM - Datagridview Column not found on two fields

Tags: c#, mysql

Help, I already searched problems regarding this issue and I haven't been successful yet. So here it is, I was trying to display a record into specific textboxes if you try to click a cell in a datagrid view, but i get an error on 2 column (Column named Age cannot be found. Parameter name: columnName) same as the Occupation column, the rest is fine)  First click on a cell will show the age cannot be found while the second one is occupation. 
Here is my code on cellclick event of the datagridview:

```
{
        try

        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = this.ViewPatients.Rows[e.RowIndex];

                txtPatientID.Text = row.Cells["PatientID"].Value.ToString();
                txtFirstname.Text = row.Cells["Firstname"].Value.ToString();
                txtMiddleName.Text = row.Cells["Middlename"].Value.ToString();
                txtLastname.Text = row.Cells["Lastname"].Value.ToString();
                cmbGender.Text = row.Cells["Gender"].Value.ToString();
                txtAge.Text = row.Cells["Age"].Value.ToString();
                txtContact.Text = row.Cells["Contact"].Value.ToString();
                txtAddress.Text = row.Cells["Address"].Value.ToString();
                txtBirthDate.Text = row.Cells["BirthDate"].Value.ToString();
                cmbCivilStatus.Text = row.Cells["CivilStatus"].Value.ToString();
                txtOccupation.Text = row.Cells["Occupation"].Value.ToString();


            }
        }
        catch (Exception z)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was a problem" + z.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your grid apparently doesn't have an Age or Occupation column. But how do you get to the code that accesses Occupation if Age throws an exception?

Comment: I literally have no idea at all, On my previous system (library management system) I used to have the same exact code and flow for that and it works fine, clicking on any cell in a datagridview would then display that reocord into specific textboxes in order to update. But this present system I am devoloping, turns out to be a conflict.

Comment: In the debugger (or did you use the designer?) inspect your grid columns. I suspect you might have missed a couple when naming, probably they are still named "Column6" or whatever.

Comment: I didnt inspect my grid columns, can you help me out?  I guess this is because the naming is different or so? I have no Idea on how to find out. This problem is draining up my time until the deadline and I am really feeling bad about this.

Comment: Just put a break point after you bind your grid to your data and use the locals window to drill into its columns property.

Comment: Do you have any other idea / suggestions in order to fix this? was this because of the designer.cs ? Because I made changes on my query as well as fields on my database before this happened. Your statement is a bit deep and frankly i couldn't understand it. ( I'm a 3rd year college student ) I apologize for not being able to understand your statement.

Comment: You really need to learn basic debugging or you will stumble through everything you do. If you can find where the grid is databound in code  you can put the curosr on any statement below it then press F9. When you run your program the debugger will stop there. You can right-click the variable and choose to watch it. Additionally, you can access columns by index instead of name. This is usually not ideal but it may get you moving again. So instead of `row.Cells["Age"]...` use the index (whatever position it is, I don't know this is example) : `row.Cells[6]...`